# Intuitive explanation of why electrode potential of a metal- metal insoluble salt- anion half cell is same as metal-metal ion cell?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

My physical chemistry professor in his electrochemistry class derived before us, the formula of the electrode potential for a metal- metal insoluble salt- anion half cell and after a few minutes of putting formulas here and there he finally proved before us that t**he electrode potential for a metal- metal ion electrode and metal- metal insoluble salt-anion electrode is/comes out to be the same**, the formula appeals to me, however, **I don't quite get the intuition and the reason behind the same**.
Is it because the anion plays a dormant/ insignificant role in the process, if so then why to take it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The excess of anion ( like $\ce{Cl-}$ ) determines via the solubility product ( like $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{AgCl})  = [\ce{Ag+}][\ce{Cl-}]$ ) the concentration of the metal cation ( like $\ce{Ag+}$ ).

So for the silver chloride reference electrode:

$$\begin{align}
E(\ce{Ag/Ag+})&=E^{\circ}(\ce{Ag/Ag+}) + 0.059 \log {([\ce{Ag+}])} \\ 
&= E^{\circ}(\ce{Ag/Ag+}) + 0.059 \log {(K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{AgCl}))}  - 0.059 \log {([\ce{Cl-}])} \\
&= E^{\circ}(\ce{Ag/AgCl/Cl-}) - 0.059 \log {([\ce{Cl-}])}
\end{align}$$